# Setting the ants path in batch file

Tags: ant, batch-file

I have a batch file in which I set the ant path and junit path values hard coded and it executes my `build.xml` and everything works fine.

When I replace the hard coded value of the path with something like
`set Path=%CURRENT DIRECTORY%\bin`
it is not working.

How to make this work.

Here is my batch file

```
set CURRENT_DIRECTORY=%~dp0

set ANT_HOME=c:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.3
ECHO current directory is %CURRENT_DIRECTORY%
ECHO %ANT_HOME%
set Path=%ANT_HOME%\bin
set ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH=%1
set USER_JAR_PATH=%2
set CLASS_NAME=%3
set RESULTS_PATH=%4
set JUNIT_PATH=C:\ANT\test\junit-4.1.jar
set LIBRAIES_TO_INCLUDE="%JUNIT_PATH%";"%ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH%";"%USER_JAR_PATH%"
ECHO %LIBRAIES_TO_INCLUDE%
ECHO %ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH%
ECHO %JUNIT_PATH%
ECHO %USER_JAR_PATH%
ECHO %CLASS_NAME%
ECHO %RESULTS_PATH% 

ant -lib "%LIBRAIES_TO_INCLUDE%" -Dlibraries="%ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH%" -Djunitlibrary="%JUNIT_PATH%" -Djartobeexec="%USER_JAR_PATH%" -Duserclass=%CLASS_NAME% -Dresultspath=%RESULTS_PATH% -buildfile build.xml test-html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

SET ANT_HOME = ant_directory
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -cp %ANT_HOME%/lib/ant-launcher.jar -Dant.home="%ANT_HOME%" -Dant.library.dir="%ANT_HOME%/lib" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -f  build.xml %*

Comment: Hey @prabhu can you up vote, if my suggestion helped you to solve your problem ?

Comment: Hey Sujith my Reputation is below par so i cant vote.I l surely vote once i become eligible.Thanx man

Comment: +1 for working solution :) Prabhu RK - you can reselect this answer as a accepted answer.